# Main does not run (SDL, Cmake, Windows VSCode)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

A am writing small game in C++, SDL2 (using Cmake) and my main function does not run.
Code Structure:

```
/build
/external
    external.cmake
    sdl2.cmake
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

I guess external folder is not important at all, but I will include it.
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


project(mygame)


find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/external.cmake)
add_executable(mygame main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mygame PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2main)
target_link_libraries(mygame PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2-static)
target_link_libraries(mygame PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2)
```

main.cpp:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int args, char** argv)
{
    printf("Ready");
    return 0;
}
```

external.cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external)
include(sdl2)
```

sdl2.cmake:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    sdl2
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL"
    GIT_TAG "2.0.22"
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sdl2)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Everything builds, but when I want to run the program it does nothing (does not print "Ready" as it should).
I use GCC 12.2.0 x86_64_w64-mingw32 compiler.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your program build, or do you get errors?

Comment: It's good form to use `/n` with `printf`, or `fflush(stdout)`, to ensure that output buffers get flushed. Or just use `puts` when you just want to get a debug line up on the screen.

Comment: It does build [build] Build finished with exit code 0